# A generic way for extracting the URI of the favicon of any webpage

Tags: java, httpurlconnection, favicon

Is there a generic way for extracting the URI of the favicon of any webpage?

Initially, I thought I could use Java / HttpURLConnection, read the XML and parse it.

But I doubt that there is a finite number of methods for placing a favicon in a webpage.

Note that I want to retrieve the URI of the favicon, not to download the favicon image itself.

Any idea would be highly appreciated.

Thanks

### UPDATE:

Here is one idea that comes to mind, though I doubt it would work for **every** webpage out there:

1. Read the HTML into a string via URL connection.
2. Search the string for the next occurrence of `"favicon"`.
3. Find the `"` delimiters that encapsulate it on both sides.
4. If the result begins with `"http"`, then return it as is.
5. If the result begins with `"\"`, then return it prefixed by the URL of the webpage.
6. Go back to step #2.

Answer (score 1):

**favicon**

You should first use your favorite search engine to find out how "favicon" items are published so that browsers know where to load. You will find more info, but probably the most common way is to place following link in html/head:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/i_dont_name_it_fav_icon.ico" />
```

**Parsing HTML**

I'm afraid your idea won't be successful in many cases. Since HTML is not XML, better use [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) to extract the information you need.

**Crawling / Loading Pages**

Before using HttpURLConnection I recommend using a library for loading web resources, because HttpURLConnection is not easy to use. If it's hard to find a good library, check out [Apache Http Client](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/). I've implemented a small wrapper over HttpURLConnection: [DavidWebb](http://hgoebl.github.io/DavidWebb/). It's leightweight and easy to use.